# Noun form of 'owe'?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

If I've paid somebody $100, the $100 is my *payment*. If I owed someone $100, would the $100 be an ***owement***? Is there a better word? I could call it *debt* or *loan*, but it doesn't quite suit the following example:

Say two people Alice and Bob maintained a common expenses spreadsheet online to track who owed who how much. Would it be appropriate to name that sheet '***Alice-Bob Owements***'?

Comment: 'Alice-Bob Debts' would be a perfectly good title in your example: why don't you like it?

Comment: @TimLymington: Maybe it's just me, but I thought 'Alice-Bob Debts' (or 'Alice-Bob Loans') sounded like they together owed _someone else_. `owement` was so apt, except there's no such word! Oh well..

Comment: Why not say "Debts Between Bob and Alice"?

Comment: What you seem to be describing is a *balance sheet*.

Comment: This question of mine is over 4 years old and is suddenly getting attention! I'm 4 years older too, and hopefully wiser, and I can see that _owement_ sounds stupid and made-up! I've accepted the **_debt/dues_** answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Debt** sounds good for your spreadsheet. In prose, try **due**, as in "get your due."

Answer (score 4):

*If I've paid somebody $100, the $100 is my payment*-You **acquitted** your obligation or [to settle or satisfy (a debt, obligation, claim, etc.).](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/acquitted)

*If I owed someone $100, would the $100 be an* 
**obligation** or [the act of binding or obliging oneself by a promise, contract, etc.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/obligation)

Comment: How this can be considered as a good answer? It does not relate to the given example (from the question) at all.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably referring to a *credit and debit list*

Answer (score 2):

You could use the noun **Borrowing** : `something that is borrowed`

> Alice-Bob Borrowings

Answer (score -1):

> Say two people Alice and Bob maintained a common expenses spreadsheet
>   online to track who owed who how much. Would it be appropriate to name
>   that sheet 'Alice-Bob Owements'?

There is a term IOU (stands for 'I owe you') which would work nicely for this spreadsheet purposes, but not sure if it's a good option for other cases.

So it could be *'Alice-Bob IOUs'*

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/IOU